# C program for executing 'echo' on a target with no /bin directory

Tags: c, linux

Let us say I cross-compile this code for ARM from a host Linux system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void) {

   return execl ("/bin/echo", "echo", NULL);

}
```

I got a binary echoFromC

The problem is on my target where this binary would run, has no /bin, /usr etc. So it will not execute the command.

So I want that the final binary should contain every thing required to excute "echo". It shouild not look for /bin/echo (since it is not there).

How do I do this?

Actually I have to implement:

```
bash> echo 240 > /sys/class/gpio/export
bash> echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio240/direction
bash> echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio240/value
```

in a c program

Comment: Why do you need `echo` in the first place? Why not just call `printf()` in your C code?

Comment: The you need to implement `echo` in your program instead of call `system("/bin/echo", ...`.

Comment: what do you mean everything to execute echo? Do you need to find a path to an executable or just print on stdout?

Comment: kindly see my update at the bottom

Comment: @perreal I guess he wants to include the executable `/bin/echo` somehow in his `echoFromC`, but he is doing cross-compiling, that would not make sense unless he include the target version of `echo`.

Comment: @user2799508 You could simply open those files, write the corresponding strings to them, and close them. There is no need to use `/bin/echo`.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement those `echo` functions in C, for example to implement `echo 240 > /sys/class/gpio/export`, you could do something like

```
FILE *fh;

fh = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w+");
if (fh == NULL) { /* fopen failed */ }

fwrite("240\n", 1, 4, fh);

fclose(fh);
```

Comment: Is there any specific requirement of "\n" in fwrite ?

Comment: @user2799508 `echo` will add a newline at the end of its output, unless you are using `-n` option.